# The following element is no longer available when applying Coded UI test To Application

Tags: internet-explorer, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

I m getting Trouble while doing Coded UI test in Visual Studio 12.it is Showing Incompatiblity with IE10 and also not picking element of DOM proper I also Provided ID NAme and all properties then it is also giving same error why this prob is coming?

> The following element is no longer available:IE web control; Process Id [7740]

I am getting the following error while running an recorded test, First time it worked properly but when i was running the same test again it got failed and it is happening again and again with different different elements/components present on the webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO please Download Update For the Visual studio 12 to resolve this problem automatically it get solved..

The following element is no longer available:IE web control; Process Id [7740] this problem often come because of the searching criteria of visual studio which is automatically created code with update YOu can solve this prob.best idea to use the VS2013